# Is there no easy way to get back to SO/Meta from Winterbash?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2013

Unless I'm missing something, there doesn't appear to be a link back to SO/Meta from the [Winterbash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) page.  Any chance we can get the new top bar on that site since it allows quick access to all sites?

Comment: The site is not only for SO, though. There should be links to all sites.

Comment: Yeah, the Meta Beta header links to all SE sites.  That's why I didn't just ask for a link to Meta and SO.

Comment: You should answer this question yourself and get a hat.

Answer (score 1):

No, there currently is no easy way to get back to Meta or SO from Winter Bash.  However, you can either hit your browser's back button, or use the link at the bottom of the page to return to SE.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, then type S and hit enter (assuming SO is your most frequently visited S site!). */grin*

In all seriousness: Winter Bash will not be getting the new top bar, and since it is a network initiative, linking to SO in the header doesn't solve everyone's use cases. Each site's [leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) does link back to the site at the top, though.

Comment: What about making the user name on the top right link to the Network Profile of the user? Doesn't sound like much work, and from there it's easy to reach any other site. :)